# how to access xtext runtime instance in another runtime instance

Tags: xtext

I have three xtext project with same grammar. I want to access the runtime instance of 1st and 2nd project in 3rd runtime instance.

Please guide me.

[This is my Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2koo.jpg)

Regards,
Misbah.

Comment: can you please be more precise in what you want to achieve

Comment: I have three xtext projects with same grammar, we can say they are replicas. I have created runtime instances of project 1 and project 2. Now I want to copy these instances in the runtime of project 3. Hope its bit clear now

Comment: i cannot follow you. if you want to have multiple dsls (with different extensions) in onme eclipse they need to reside in one eclipse. i am not sure if i understand what you want to do as i am not sure if you name things in eclipse with the terms they are intended to be named.

Comment: I have added image. please see. I need to copy these two instances in third instance (having same grammar). Please guide.

Comment: do you want files from one model project visible in another? or just import projects from one workspace to another?

Comment: I need to access the runtime instance (if I am clear now... ) and copy it to other project's runtime instance (bit clear? :/ ) ... actually I  need a starting point in this scenario please.

Comment: i dont understand. eclipse has workspaces. you can start an instance at one workspace only. if you start two instances at the same you need different workspaces. Workspaces have projects. you can import projects in a physical location to multiple workspaces using import dialog and untick copy. if you want to have two grammars in one (runtime) workspace you need to develop both in the same development workspace.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.